# To find the value of $\lim \frac{U_{n+1}}{U_{n}}$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $0< U_{1} < 1$ and $U_{n +1} = 1-\sqrt{1-U_n}$ then find the value of $\lim \frac{U_{n+1}}{U_{n}} $ as $n$ tends to $\infty$

I was thinking about writing the recursive relation in some other form and then dividing the terms by $ U_{n}$

I wrote it 
$\sqrt{1-U_{n}} = 1 - U_{n+1}$

$(U_{n+1})^{2} = 2U_{n+1} - U_{n}$

Then I'm stuck.

How to find the limit$?$

Answer (score 3):

If you set $V_n=1-U_n$, you get $V_{n+1}=\sqrt{V_n}$. This means that
$V_n=c^{1/2^n}$ for a constant $c$ with $0<c<1$. It's better to write this
as $V_n=\exp(-t/2^n)$ where $t$ is a positive constant. Thus
$$\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}=\frac{1-\exp(-t/2^{n+1})}{1-\exp(-t/2^n)}
\sim\frac{t/2^{n+1}}{t/2^n}=\frac12.$$

Comment: Hoping that you don't mind, I added soem intermediate steps. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

*"Almost" the same idea as Lord Shark the Unknown.*

Using $$V_n=1-U_n\implies V_{n+1}=\sqrt{V_n}\implies \log(V_{n+1})=\frac12 \log(V_n)$$ Then continue with $$W_n=\log(V_n)\implies W_{n+1}=\frac12 W_n\implies W_n=c\, 2^{1-n}$$

$$V_n=\exp(W_n)\implies V_n=\exp(c\, 2^{1-n})\implies U_n=1-\exp(c\, 2^{1-n})$$
$$\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}=\frac{1-\exp(c\, 2^{-n}) } {1-\exp(c\, 2^{1-n}) }$$ and continue with Taylor expansions as  Lord Shark the Unknown did.